# How to set the position of a gameobject into initial position after grabbing ended using hand in SteamVR using Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, steamvr

Pretty new to VR.I took a gameobject from an intial position by grabbing.When I grab a helmet and touch my body collider it hides the helmet.So next I may pick glasses and apply it to my body(Hides the GameObject).Next when I put the Incorrect Helmet the first helmet should go back to its initial position and should be seen in the scene.Similarily there are many GameObjects in the scene

```
 private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{        

    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Helmet")
    {

       
        HideGameObject();
      
       
    }

    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Glasses")
    {

        HideGameObject();           
       
    }
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "EarMuff")
    {
        HideGameObject();
       
    }
   
    

    if (other.gameObject.tag == "IncorrectHelmet")
    {

      
        HideGameObject();
       

    }

    if (other.gameObject.tag == "IncorrectGlasses")
    {
        HideGameObject();
        

    }


    if (other.gameObject.tag == "IncorrectEarMuff")
    {
        HideGameObject();
        sendPickValues.Invoke(2, 0);

    }
    


 }
```

//Another script to set the GameObjects position

```
public class BackToPosition : MonoBehaviour
{

private Vector3 initialPosition;
private Quaternion initialRotation;

GameObject prevObject;
GameObject currObject;



// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    initialPosition = transform.position;
    initialRotation = transform.rotation;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    
}

public void BackToInitialPosition()
{
    Debug.Log("Entered");
    transform.position = initialPosition;
    transform.rotation = initialRotation;
                               
    
}
}
```

I am not trying to set the previous grabbed object to initial position.I may select wrong helmet first and pick many other matching gameobjects and later change to correct helmet.At that time first helmet should go to initial position.

Answer (score 1):

This is a script that I use in SteamVR to grab and release a boat's rudder handle but it should be usable for you too:

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(Interactable))]
public class HandAttacher : MonoBehaviour
{
    public UnityEvent OnGrab;
    public UnityEvent OnRelease;
    public UnityEvent OnHandEnter;
    public UnityEvent OnHandLeave;

    private Interactable interactable;

    void Awake()
    {
        interactable = GetComponent<Interactable>();
    }

    /// this magic method is called by hand while hovering
    protected virtual void HandHoverUpdate(Hand hand)
    {
        GrabTypes startingGrabType = hand.GetGrabStarting();

        if (interactable.attachedToHand == null && startingGrabType != GrabTypes.None)
        {
            hand.AttachObject(gameObject, startingGrabType, Hand.AttachmentFlags.DetachFromOtherHand | Hand.AttachmentFlags.ParentToHand);
            OnGrab?.Invoke();
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnHandHoverBegin(Hand hand)
    {
        OnHandEnter?.Invoke();
    }

    protected virtual void OnHandHoverEnd(Hand hand)
    {
        OnHandLeave?.Invoke();
    }

    protected virtual void HandAttachedUpdate(Hand hand)
    {
        if (hand.IsGrabEnding(gameObject))
        {
            hand.DetachObject(gameObject);
            OnRelease?.Invoke();
        }
    }
}
```

Basically it creates Unity Events that you can add Listeners to in the Editor's Inspector window, or in code.

So in your use case, I would add a listener to `OnRelease`, and reset the GameObject's position and rotation to whatever it was before.

Comment: How to get the initial position of the gameobjects.Say I have around 30 Gameobjects how will I get the initial position.Do I need to add this scriprt to all gameobjects? and use this concept  ` private Vector3 oldPosition`mentioned in my script to save the positions and on release use this position for gameobject to back to initial position.

Comment: Yes you add this script to anything you want to be able to attach to your hand. And on grab, remember the transform's position and rotation. On release, restore it to those values. If you don't want to use events and listeners, just edit those out of the above class and restore the rotation and position in the code itself.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using BackToPosition or something similar in Update comparing the original position to its current to reset the object's position, and the object keeps resetting on a loop instead of resetting to its original position and stopping.